# Spring не создает объект, выдает исключение, что у класса некорректное свойство

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

При загрузки страницы регистрации пользователя, на которой есть объект соответствующий классу DTO, Spring не создает объект, выдает исключение, что у класса некорректное свойство:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException:
> Invalid property ''userName'' of bean class
> [com.vs.authorizationService.DTOentity.UserDTO]: Bean property
> ''userName'' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the
> return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?     at
> org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:622)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:612)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:104)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:228)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:129)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]  at
> org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:253)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]    ... 88 common frames
> omitted

Перед этим он ещё выкидывает исключение, что у thymeleaf как раз проблемы с извлечением данного свойства у объекта:

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during
> execution of processor
> 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor'
> (template: "registration" - line 45, col 54)  at
> org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.engine.StandaloneElementTag.beHandled(StandaloneElementTag.java:228)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]

Не пойму, почему? Все проверил по 3 раза.
Объект DTO, который добавляю в модель страницы:

```
    public class UserDTO {

    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String repeatPassword;

    private String wordCoder;

    private String email;

    
    public UserDTO() {
    }


    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getRepeatPassword() {
        return repeatPassword;
    }

    public String getWordCoder() {
        return wordCoder;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setRepeatPassword(String repeatPassword) {
        this.repeatPassword = repeatPassword;
    }

    public void setWordCoder(String wordCoder) {
        this.wordCoder = wordCoder;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Контроллер:

```
Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private RequestService requestService;
    @Autowired
    private MessageService messageService;
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    private String repeatPasswordDontMatch="Passwords";

        
   
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String getlogin()
    {
        return  "login";
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String login()
    {
        return  "login";
    }


    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String getRegistration(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("user", new UserDTO());

        return  "registration";
    }

    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public String registrationNewUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") UserDTO userDTO, BindingResult bindingResult){

        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            //Остаемся на той же странице
            return "/registration";
        }
        if(!userDTO.getRepeatPassword().equals(userDTO.getPassword())){
            //Генерируем ошибку
            bindingResult.rejectValue("password",repeatPasswordDontMatch+"не совпадают!");
            return "/registration";
        }
        return "/registration:/login";
    }
```

}

Фрагмент самой страницы, на которой возникает ошибка:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row py-2">
        <div class="col-12">
            <form th:action="@{/registration}" method="post" th:object="${user}">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">User name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" th:field="*{'userName'}" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter user name">
                    <small class="form-text text-danger" th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('userName')}" th:text="${err}">Validation error</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" th:field="*{'password'}" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                    <small class="form-text text-danger" th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('password')}" th:text="${err}">Validation error</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="repeatPassword">Repeat password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="repeatPassword" th:field="*{'repeatPassword'}" class="form-control" placeholder="Repeat password">
                    <small class="form-text text-danger" th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('repeatPassword')}" th:text="${err}">Validation error</small>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div> </div>
```

Вот в этой строке возникает исключения Таймлиф:

```
<input type="text" id="username" th:field="*{'userName'}" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter user name">
```

Comment: Вообще выглядит всё правильно. Можно ссылку на гит если это не секретный проект?

Comment: @wigravy, да конечно, вот ссылка https://github.com/Voloodya/messager.git

Comment: Собственно всё запустил и проверил, ответ ниже правильный, уберите одинарные кавычки и форма корректно загружается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего вы откуда-то скопировали имя проперти обекта `user` с ковычками, что и привело к вашей ошибке. Более подробно о синтаксисе можно посмотреть здесь: [Expressions on selections (asterisk syntax)](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#expressions-on-selections-asterisk-syntax). А код должен выглядеть так ...

```
<input type="text" id="username" th:field="*{userName}" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter user name">
```

Comment: Да, вы правы. Спасибо!